# Appending line from a file into char array

Tags: c++

```
char wordList[200];
ifstream wordListFile ("wordlist.txt");


for(std::string line; getline(wordListFile, line); ) {
        wordListFile >> wordList;
}
```

This code currently returns the line at the end of the wordListFile (wordlist.txt),

is there any way to append the lines to wordList?

because when I use the append() function it returns an error.

Comment: I would expect that appending to files is discussed in every introductory C++ textbook, something in yours' about it is unclear? What is it, specifically?

Comment: english please?

Comment: You are losing `line` and getting a word on a next line.

Comment: @fatcat what of that English is unclear please? I'm not a native speaker, but it renders perfectly well for me?

Comment: You cannot append anything to a char array. Array size is fixed.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. so what can i use instead of the array?

Comment: I store my strings in `std::string`.

Comment: "because when I use the append() function it returns an error." -- You may want to show your attempt of using `append` as a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop

```
for(std::string line; getline(wordListFile, line); ) {
        wordListFile >> wordList;
```

you are reading one line of input with `getline(wordListFile, line);`, but not doing anything with that line. Instead, you are reading the first word of the next line with `wordListFile >> wordList;`. This does not make sense.

If you want to append the line contents to `wordList`, then you could initialize `wordList` as an empty string and then use [`std::strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char wordList[200] = "";
    std::ifstream wordListFile( "wordlist.txt" );

    for ( std::string line; std::getline(wordListFile, line); ) {
        std::strcat( wordList, line.c_str() );
    }

    std::cout << wordList << '\n';
}
```

For the input

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
```

this program has the following output:

```
This is line 1.This is line 2.
```

As you can see, the lines were correctly appended.

However, this code is dangerous, because if the file is too large for the array `wordList`, then you will have a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

A safer and more efficient approach would be to make `wordList` of type `std::string` instead of a C-style string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string wordList;
    std::ifstream wordListFile( "wordlist.txt" );

    for ( std::string line; std::getline(wordListFile, line); ) {
        wordList += line;
    }

    std::cout << wordList << '\n';
}
```

This program has the same output:

```
This is line 1.This is line 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `append` on a `std::string` but your `wordList` is a char array.

Also a string isn't a list. Probably (but I am guessing) you want code something like this

```
std::vector<std::string> wordList;
for (std::string word; wordListFile >> word; ) {
    wordList.push_back(word);
}
```

Here `wordList` is a vector of strings, and `push_back` adds each word that you read to that vector.

If you actually want to append lines not words to a list then just use `getline` instead of `>>`

```
std::vector<std::string> lineList;
for (std::string line; getline(wordListFile, line); ) {
    lineList.push_back(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> because when I use the append() function it returns an error.

[`std::string::append (2)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) works well.

```
std::string wordList;
ifstream wordListFile ("wordlist.txt");

for(std::string line; getline(wordListFile, line); ) {
    wordList.append(line);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
std::string wordList;
std::ifstream wordListFile ;

wordListFile.open("wordlist.txt");
std::getline(wordListFile , wordList);
wordListFile.close();
```

Try this code. You could get whole string from the file.
I wish this can help you.